# nodejs - through package - make requests synchronous

Tags: node.js

I was doing nodeschool's stream-adventure - 6 and this is my code ([question here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/substack/stream-adventure/master/problems/http_server/problem.txt)):

```
var capitalize = through(function (chunk) {
    this.queue(chunk.toString().toUpperCase() + '\n')
})

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.pipe(capitalize).pipe(response)
})
```

here's what a test run looks like (https://dpaste.de/mzn3)

while this doesn't work, this one does:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.pipe(through(function (chunk) {
        this.queue(chunk.toString().toUpperCase() + '\n')
    })).pipe(response)
})
```

this one's test run: https://dpaste.de/rNT2

I think its because the the first one is non-blocking and that is why I am getting response of some request after some other responses, but how is it non-blocking and second one blocking? Requests to server do work in parallel, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're using the same through stream instance for multiple simultaenous requests.

If you still want to keep it separated out, you could do something like:

```
function makeCapitalize() {
  return through(function (chunk) {
    this.queue(chunk.toString().toUpperCase() + '\n')
  })
}

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  request.pipe(makeCapitalize()).pipe(response)
})
```